# Find duplicate slugs with regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex to highlight the circular redirects in these 301 redirects.

I'm using Sublime Text, and only need to highlight them, so I can manually edit.

The example below is from a much bigger file.

```
Redirect 301 /en/about/about /en/about
Redirect 301 /en/about/global /en/about/global
Redirect 301 /en/about/divisions /en/about/divisions
Redirect 301 /en/division /en/about/divisions
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which two in your sample do demonstrate a circular redirect?

Comment: Lines 1 and 2 are the circular redirects

Comment: lines 2 and 3 you mean?

Comment: Ah, yes sorry! Lines 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first remove from capturing the 2 first strings and the spaces `"Redirect 301 "`

Then, capturing the next string to the space. Then capture the last one as backreference

```
^(?:.*\s){2}(.*)(?:\s)(\1)$
```

Output :

```
Redirect 301 /en/about/about /en/about // doesn't match
Redirect 301 /en/about/global /en/about/global // match
Redirect 301 /en/about/divisions /en/about/divisions // match
Redirect 301 /en/division /en/about/divisions // doesn't match
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9ZiiwD/2)

Comment: That's great! Thanks for your help.

Comment: This also could be shortened to `\h(\S+)\h+\1(?!\S)`

Comment: @revo feel free to edit my answer if you want to add and explain this one, or create a new answer, I'll happily upvote this. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a poor question that I avoid to post an answer. I shouldn't edit this answer either since I said an alternative (probably a better one) exists and it's up to answerer to ask *why?* otherwise we'd better leave it as just a simple comment.